# My Printer is HP LaserJet 1020 Plus does not print

Tags: printing, hp

My printer is HP LaserJet 1020 Plus. I cannot print anything, I have noticed in the settings menu "Not calibrated".

What is the procedure to calibrate? Please explain with simple language.

Comment: If that doesn't help, could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

HP say this device needs a plug-in ... so you gotta have that ..

So if you open a terminal; (hold down the control and alt and t keys ..)

Then type `hp-setup` that should recognize the need for the plug-in and install it

[This](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html) gives more detail on plug-ins